# ansible loop through list item condition gives error

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I am trying to following but I am getting this error "The conditional check 'item.vrf = 'default'' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got '='. String: {% if item.vrf = 'default' %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}" how to fix it?

```
proc_vrf: [{''proc'': ''T1'', ''vrf'': ''default''}, {''proc'': ''T2'', ''vrf'': ''vrf_T2''}, {''proc'': ''T3'', ''vrf'': ''default''}, {''proc'': ''T3'', ''vrf'': ''vrf_T3''}]


 - name: Shut ospf for default vrf
    cisco.nxos.nxos_config:
      lines:
      - shutdown
      parents: router ospf {{ item.proc }}
      save_when: modified
    when: item.vrf|lower == 'default'
    with_items: "{{ proc_vrf }}"

 - name: Shut ospf for other vrf
    cisco.nxos.nxos_config:
      lines:
      - shutdown
      parents: router ospf {{ item.proc }}; vrf {{ proc_vrf }}
      save_when: modified
    when: item.vrf|lower != 'default'
    with_items: "{{ proc_vrf }}"
```

Comment: Your condition (`when`) is a task parameter (and can be applied to any task), not a parameter specific to that module. So, you need to outdent the `when` statement once.

Comment: Thanks. I got this error now: The conditional check 'item.vrf = 'default'' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got '='. String: {% if item.vrf = 'default' %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}

Comment: That’s quite explanatory, isn’t it? `=` is not a comparison operator, `==` or `!=` are.

Comment: thx, fixed it. can these 2 tasks be merged to 1 task? how?

Answer (score 0):

There was an operator error. corrected comparison operator, ==